# PostgisDialect vs PostgreSQLDialect or both?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, postgis, hibernate-spatial

My application is going to use the following technologies:

- Postgresql
- Postgis
- JPA/Hibernate
- Spring
- Spring Data JPA

I understand (from the Hibernate Spatial documentation) that one has to use the following dialect: `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect`

What I don't understand though is how the above dialect relates to the standard Posgresql dialect, i.e. `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`...

Is the Postgis dialect a superset of the standard Posgresql dialect?

Will all features of the latest standard Posgresql dialect be available in the Postgis dialect?

I guess I can't use several/multiple dialects on the same entityManager factory... Then what are the best practices to get the best of both dialects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PostgisDialect actually extends the Postgresql dialect, so, yes, it is a superset. See the class declaration: [PostgisDialect class declaration](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/javadoc/4.0/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/postgis/PostgisDialect.html)

There is a good tutorial here: [Hibernate spatial with Postgis](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/02-Tutorial/01-tutorial4/) that show that you only need to include the Postgis Dialect in order to persist both spatial and non-spatial fields.

Postgis primary provides support for spatial objects on top of Postgresql. A Postgis installation also includes GEOS (a C++ port of Java Topology Suite) which provides many of the actual geometric functions, Proj4, which provides support for different coordinate systems/projections and GDAL, which is a conversion utility between various geographical data formats.

Comment: Apply to Grails 4